# Problems with the keys to face API from cognitive services

Tags: c#

Please someone can help i need to get keys to face api from cognitive services to develop the project "facerecognitiondoor" from hackster.io i am new in this type of projects someones can help me step by step to get the keys to face api thanks

Answer (score 0):

for the API keys you have to log into my account.
post log in you has to subscribe the face API service .
post subscription you will get the keys of Face API.

for more detail help watch the suggested video :
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SEgTpICy4vI